# Tomcat HttpSession Cookie Shared

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, session-cookies

I have several separate instances of the same web application running on different servers (all have different public facing IPs).  I make use of sessions to store currently logged in user's information.

```
HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);     

User user = (User)session.getAttribute("user");
if (user == null) {
  // get my user
  session.setMaxInactiveInterval(....);
  session.setAttribute("user", user);
}
```

The problem is that when I log in to one instance (call it instance 1) and then log in to another (instance 2) then when I switch to instance 1 it picks up the cookie for instance 2 and obviously creates a problem when the user which such an id doesn't exist on instance 1 and even worse when it silently just finds the user that matches that id..

I've looked at the cookies and only one `JSESSIONID` cookie is created with domain of "localhost" and it is shared with all instances. Is there a way to set Tomcat to set the domain to be the domain of the machine?

I'm running Tomcat 6.0.35

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `defaultHost` to the `hostname` (or network name) of the server.
Have a look at Tomcat's `conf/server.xml` configuration file:

```
<Engine ... defaultHost="myserver">
```

Then you'll also need to change:

```
<Host ... name="myserver">
```

See:
 
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/engine.html
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html

As another possible solution you can define `jvmRoute` as the "unique name" for each instance.

```
<Engine ... jvmRoute="instance1">
```

This will generate a `JSESSIONID` like:

```
C85262796BE5F656BD8EF58A96F03C96.instance1
```